Inquiry Regarding "Job Failed Due to Heartbeat Error"
I've come across an error message indicating "Job failed due to heartbeat error." Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to address it? Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.


Does this help? https://status.cloud.sitecore.net/status?id=pub&sysid=6b9b498a1b8c4ed0efd0ec22604bcb3e

Very useful, thank you @DeanOBrien

hey you can check this https://status.cloud.sitecore.net/status?id=pub&sysid=6b9b498a1b8c4ed0efd0ec22604bcb3e hope this helps !!

In the off chance that the link provided in the comments is removed/unpublished, I will add an answer here for anyone else having the same issue.
The error "Job Failed Due to Heartbeat Error" appears to be related to the API Crawler wthin the Sitecore Search Platform. The linked article identifies that "the cause stemmed from a capacity limitation in one of our infrastructure resource" and can be resolved by "increasing the capacity to an appropriate level".

Sitecore Incident Reference - Incident Tracker ID: INC0813750

Assuming this is referring to capacity within Sitecore Search. I can only assume it means to increase the 'parallelism' within the API Crawler settings in the customer search console.  @JitendraSoni -  Did you find this to be the solution? Or was it referring to the resource being crawled?

This is a Sitecore error that gets resolved by Sitecore engineering teams.
It can impact source infrastructure related tasks, like reindexing, recrawling and partial updates pushed via the ingestion API.
The official route is to raise a support ticket and have Sitecore look into it. The link other have shared is also good for monitoring service health, but changing the parallelism setting won't do anything for this.
As runtime services are actively monitored, you will typically see a resolution before the official support SLAs.
